# as3 loaded swf accessing variables

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, flash, external

I have some questions with sharing/using/accessing variables/functions between loaded swf files.
my prj consists of main.swf file and 2 swf's which I load on first init of the main.swf.
my questions are:
1.how can I use variables from 1.swf in 2.swf (function is running in 2.swf)
2.how can I call a function from 2.swf in 1.swf

here is the code I'm using to load the swf's:

```
var playerMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var dbMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var m2Loader:Loader = new Loader();
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();

startLoad();
function startLoad()
{
    //var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("./_player/player.swf");
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadMc);
    mLoader.load(mRequest);
    addChild(mLoader);

    //var m2Loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var m2Request = new URLRequest("./_db/db.swf");
    m2Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadMc2);
    m2Loader.load(m2Request);
    addChild(m2Loader);
}
function loadMc(event:Event):void
{
    if (! event.target)
    {
        return;
    }
    playerMc = event.target.content as MovieClip;
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadMc);
}

function loadMc2(event:Event):void
{
    if (! event.target)
    {
        return;
    }
    dbMc = event.target.content as MovieClip;
    dbMc.x = -400;
    m2Loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadMc2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stick with application domain.
In most cases you should load another swf in another application domain, but it's not really related to your question.
From `loader`, you must access to `applicationDomain` and then `getDefinition`. From there, you can get classes and use them in your main swf. Yes, you can read static properties.
If you need instances you should access loader#content. It is pointing to a root of loaded SWF. Root of loaded is SWF – is the instance of main class of the loaded swf.

Comment: do you have an example of this? I cannot wrap my head around this.

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable with no definition such as

public var MyClass;

as you can see i didnt add

public var MyClass:Class;

then in another function write

this.MyClass = this.mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("NameOfClass") as Class;

i dont know much about this myself.. im having problems figuring out if you can only access Public static variables or if its possible to access normal public variables and possibly private variables because it is creating a new instance of the same class or however you want to word it..?

also after your write the above code .. when you want to change a varaibles this usually works for me

this.MyClass.RandomVariableName = this.MyClass.RandomVariableName + 1;

something like that..